# Pandas groupby data and do calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like below and I have reordered the dataframe depending on the value of column B.

`a = df.sort(['B', 'A'], ascending=[True, False])`

```
#This is my df    
A,B
a,2
b,3
c,4
d,5
d,6
d,7
d,9
```

Then I'd like to calculate the difference between each element in column B when column A is the same. But if column A only contain single data point then the result will be zero.

So firstly I used `groupby()` to do so.

`b = a['B'].groupby(df['A']))`

Then I stuck here, I know I can use `lambda x: abs(x[i] - x[i+1])` or even `apply()` function to finish the calculation. But I still fail to get it done.

Can anyone give me a tip or suggestion?

```
# What I want to see in the result
A,B
a,0
b,0
c,0
d,0  # 5 minus 5
d,1  # 6 minus 5
d,1  # 7 minus 6
d,2  # 9 minus 7
```

Comment: The "5 minus 5" bit is kind of a special case to handle, do you really need it?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just want to keep it as zero if the data is the first (smallest) one, which is just like single data point.

Comment: OK well if you have a good reason for it I won't argue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both the 1-member and multimember group cases, taking the `diff` will produce a nan for the first value, which we can `fillna` with 0:

```
>>> df["B"] = df.groupby("A")["B"].diff().fillna(0)
>>> df
   A  B
0  a  0
1  b  0
2  c  0
3  d  0
4  d  1
5  d  1
6  d  2
```

This assumes there aren't NaNs already there you want to preserve.  We could still make that work if we needed to.

Comment: ah you've been faster than me !

Answer (score 3):

You can do that:

```
df.groupby(level="A").B.diff().fillna(0)

A
a    0
b    0
c    0
d    0
d    1
d    1
d    2
```